# Drupal Forms API how to get degree sign onto submit button

Tags: forms

I'd like to have a submit button with "°C" value on it. But when I just copy paste the degree sign, I get an empty value. When I try HTML code for degree sign (`&deg;`) it is escaped so I get `&deg;`C.

This is my submit button element in my hook_form function:

```
$form['wrapper']['F'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => 'F',
    '#value' => '°F',
    //'#value' => '&#176; F',
    //'#value' => '&#x00B0; F',
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'fahrenheit-button'),
    '#weight' => 20,
  );
```

Any ideas? Thanks, Tomas

Comment: Show us your exact code. Using proper unicode [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nS4Zj.png).

Comment: None of the variants tried works :/ I have also checked the file's encoding and it is UTF8 which should be ok..

Comment: Do you have sth like `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your output HTML?

Comment: Yes, it's there

Comment: Now you have me. Works for me. But maybe setup I tried it on already have old hack I forgot.

Comment: Works for me on a fresh install. I think it to do with the editor your using. Are you on Mac or PC? When saving the file can you choose the character encoding to use?

Comment: I firstly have done it by copy paste trrough my Win clipboard which is Czech - I thought that will be the problem, but it wasn't. Even when I write it manually in my netBeans PHP editor, the problem persists. BUT! When I just try to make a simple try-degree-sign.php, only with echo "°"; in it, it works! Strange

Comment: Does it help if you let it run through the t() function?

Comment: Hi Lance, no, the t() function doesn't help. Tried with all combinations (°, &deg; &#x00B0;).

Comment: I think my problem is that on my laptop it is only possible to enter ° sign through Czech keyboard, and it has no numlock, so I can't use ALT+0176. Copy-pasting from character map app is doing the same even if I change win default language to ENG. It's starting to get me quite mad... Please isn't there a solution to make drupal NOT escape FAPI submit button value, so that I could use &deg; as I do everywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in Drupal by default are being generated by the `theme_button()` theme function which uses `drupal_attributes()` to handle all of the button's attributes which *always* escapes an attribute's value using `check_plain()`.

Visit [api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_button/7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_button/7) for the `theme_button()` function and click under the Code section on a function name to see what it does.

I think there are two possibilities:

1. You write your own implementation of `theme_button()`: copy the original function, paste it into your `template.php` file and rename it to something like `YOUR_THEME_button()`;
2. Or just use the bare unicode character as you did in your question. I read at [stackoverflow.com/q/3627720/328272](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627720/328272) that this does not work on Windows XP, but I successfully tested it on IE7 and IE8 on XP using [browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com).

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="submit" value="&#x00B0;C" />
```

This website is useful for converting characters: http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Comment: That's not an [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) code for submit button.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as Molot mentions I need it as a Drupal Form API element.

Comment: Sorry - I assumed that the form API would take the same value. Just tried it and it seems the API automatically converts it for you: just writing '#value' => '°C' worked for me...

Comment: @FelixEve  a lot happens between Form API array coder wrote and the result one can see on a webpage. If somehow form array is OK and result is bad, posting desired result is not helpful ;) (I would consider retracting my downvote, seeing why you posted it, but it's too late, it's locked)

Comment: No probs, someone may still find the answer useful in future, and I can cope with a down vote ;)